# how to avoid code repetition in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have javascript code that repeat i want to make it smaller or

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction1() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput1");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");

}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction2() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput2");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");

}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction3() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput3");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");

}
</script>
```

and put the variable in the function name with a loop

thank you

Comment: Can you post where `myFunction1`, etc are being invoked?

Comment: You could start by just having the one `<script>` tag..

Comment: Make a parameterised function which takes `elementId` as the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Create a single function, pass the element id and use it for getting copyText object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction(elementId) {
    var copyText = document.getElementById(elementId);
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }
</script>
```

And invoke it like this.

```
 myFunction("myInput1");
 myFunction("myInput2");
 myFunction("myInput3");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single function with a good name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function copyInputsValueToClipboard(elementId){
    const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }
</script>
```

You can then invoke the function with the `id` of the input that you want to have copied to the clipboard.

```
copyInputsValueToClipboard("myInput1");
```